# Civilization 5 crashes often during play

Tags: civilization-5

Civilization 5 crashes repeatedly on my system.  I can play for 10 minutes but then the system will crash.

I am playing Civilization 5 gods and kings (from the Gold Edition / Steam install).

Here is my system.

Here is my dxdialog and other info:
http://pastebin.com/kcT1xJKY

And then my civ 5 configuration
http://pastebin.com/7T8YbfHq

http://steamcommunity.com/app/8930/discussions/1/666826166384694500/

I also found a lot of people are having the same problem.  I don't really see a good solution in there.

http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?123668-Gods-and-Kings-keeps-crashing

I found this, there doesn't seem to be a solution (overheating and civ 5):

http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Civilization_V#Overheating

Comment: when you say you don't see a good solution in that forum thread, have you tried all the things suggested in it?

Comment: also, I notice that the version of your driver is fairly recent (their site says some time last week it was updated) -- were you able to play the game before that point?

Comment: I haven't been able to play for more than 10 minutes.

Comment: When you say the system crashes, what do you mean? Does the whole system just shut off, or Civ V closes, or what actually happens after those 10 minutes?

Comment: The whole system locks up and I have to reboot.

Comment: Very well might be hardware related. Tell us about your power supply.

Comment: Tell us how other demanding games act in long play sessions. Is this problem isolated with this game or it happens with others sometimes ?

Comment: Does it happen if you're playing in the tile view? I installed it on my laptop, and the video card fan was incredibly loud. Switching to the tile view dropped the graphics load (and quieted the fan) considerably.

Comment: @BerlinBrown I once had a possibly similar problem to what you're describing when playing games like Mass Effect 3, or Battlefield 3 on a pretty decent machine. I noticed the problem was only when the games were using DX11, when I switched to DX10 everything worked fine. It turned out my graphics card's BIOS had some kind of bug when it tried to use DX11 and it was solved by firmware update from the GPU manufacturer. Maybe try looking along these lines...

Comment: I am more a strategy person.  Done Civ 5, Civ4, Starcraft1, Starcraft2, Eve online, Diablo 3, Guild Wars2 never had issues.  I try some of the suggestions listed.

Comment: From all the forums I have read about this, everyone seems to be having this problem because Civilization 5 is a 32 bit program. This only allows it to access 4 gb of ram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am running win8 pc I had this problem before here is how I fixed it:

1. Update graphics driver
2. Run as administrator
3. Options->Video Options->GPU Texture Decode->OFf->Restart game

If it didn't work:
4. Options->Video Options->Vsync->OFf->Restart game

Comment: run Civ 5 as admin or also Steam as admn?

Comment: Didnt run civ5 with steam, I just ran the game as admin.

Comment: I will try that also. I was running through Steam.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to I've found is to

1) Use directx 9

2) turn off full screen.

Answer (score -3):

To solve this problem you can try running the game in DirectX 9 mode. If that doesn't work there are other solutions that have worked for other people.

You can find instructions for fixing Civilization 5 freezing and crashing here: http://www.thefakegeek.com/2013/12/how-to-stop-civilization-v-from-freezing-and-crashing/

Comment: Can you include the contents of the link?  So when the link no longer works your answer is still helpful?